# Showing a hidden button

Tags: ios, objective-c

Please bear with me, as I am still learning the ropes of objective c.

I currently have a button that when pressed hides the iOS keyboard. I was wondering how I could do the opposite of this. When a text field is selected, the keyboard automatically appears- at the same time, I'd like this button to also appear on screen.

Thanks!

```
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender{
//...
//...
[Screen resignFirstResponder];
done.hidden = YES;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use **NSNotification**. Implement the `addObserver` in **viewWillAppear** and `removeObserver` in **viewWillDisappear**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification{
  done.hidden = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

register for the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

and show the button in the method provided:

```
-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification{
    done.hidden = NO;
}
```

do not forget to remove the observer in dealloc with

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Comment: Make sure to remove observer in dealloc.

Comment: Of course - thanks! I'll update my answer to include this, I thought that was clear ;)

Comment: Yea, it probably is, but just in case beginners stumble on this answer, I thought it might be useful to include it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITextFieldDelegate method to achieve this for example:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    done.hidden = NO;    
    return YES;
}
```

Hope it will help.